# Why am I getting ./attempted_login.py: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find a match from console input, but I am getting an error.

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import os
import sys
import subprocess
import datetime

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    vlog = open('/var/log/secure', 'r')
    from datetime import daytime
    now = datetime.now()
else:
    try:
        fileName = sys.argv[1]
        userfile= open(fileName)

    except:
        print('Unable to open %s' % fileName)
```

Why am I getting:

```
./attempted_login.py: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `
```

Comment: some issue with the shebang first line probably. any control chars in it?. Try with "python attempted_login.py" just to check.

Comment: ...mind you, once that's fixed you'll have other bugs. There's no such thing as `datetime.daytime`, and assigning the same name multiple values during your program's execution is a recipe for unnecessary confusion.

Comment: (Also, a bare `except:` is *extremely* bad form -- much better to catch only the specific exception type you expect, such as `except IOError`, or else bugs you *don't* expect are misreported/masked).

Comment: As it is, though, this isn't reproducible with the given code -- copy-and-paste directly from the question, invoke it correctly, and a different, more-expected error happens instead. Please see the docs on building a [mcve].